# InputScope with suggestions doesn't work for Russian language

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have got a problem with using InputScope for input with suggestions.

It doesn't work for Russian language.

With official example "[Keyboard Index Sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=229113)" from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28VS.92%29.aspx) I have tried using suggestions for Russian language looks like English.

But I have got nonworking property.
See examples on attached pictures.

English suggestion - works fine!
h??ps://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=823a352ceb14dd0f&resid=823A352CEB14DD0F!181&parid=823A352CEB14DD0F!180&authkey=!ABL3u03iaDKO_5A

English suggestion - result
h??ps://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=823a352ceb14dd0f&resid=823A352CEB14DD0F!182&parid=823A352CEB14DD0F!180&authkey=!AHFXoo8MBp0Kwcg

Russian suggestion - doesn't work
h??ps://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=823a352ceb14dd0f&resid=823A352CEB14DD0F!183&parid=823A352CEB14DD0F!180&authkey=!ANsq02b9sQR_nPY

Russian suggestion - result
h??ps://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=823a352ceb14dd0f&resid=823A352CEB14DD0F!184&parid=823A352CEB14DD0F!180&authkey=!AAytqUOq528k1OU

It's strange because I saw that suggestions also don't work in some application with Russian language.

Do you know the solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance for any help!

**P.S.**
Sorry  **h??ps = https**

Reason:
Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users can only post a maximum of two hyperlinks. Earn more than 10 reputation to post more hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue wit non-latin suggestions. 
It should be fixed now.
You tried in emulator? Try on device - suggestions should work.

I think, there is no updates for 7.1 emulator about suggestions - and it's reason.